# How do I grab and send the profile picture of anyone on my server using a discord.py bot?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've been working on a discord bot using discord.py for the past few days. Now i'm trying to implement a command that displays the profile picture of anyone you mention on the server.

The problem is I can only get it to give the profile picture of the person who sends the command. I can't get it to take in a second parameter without encountering errors or the bot ignoring it.

```py
@client.command(aliases=['getprofilepic','getprofilepicture','pfp','profilepic','profilepicture','avatar'])
async def getpfp(ctx):
    await ctx.send(ctx.author.avatar_url)
```

The code above is a command to send the profile picture of the user who sends the command into the chat.
It ignores any extra parameters and thus can not display the profile picture of anyone else except the sender.

Changing `getpfp(ctx):` to `getpfp(ctx, usernamepfp):` and `ctx.send(ctx.author.avatar_url)` to `ctx.send(ctx.usernamepfp.avatar_url)` didn't work.

I also tried `ctx.send(usernamepfp.avatar_url)`.

How would I implement the command such that when one types `.getpfp @username` in the chat it would send the profile picture of `@username` and not the sender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from discord import Member

@bot.command()
async def getpfp(ctx, member: Member = None):
 if not member:
  member = ctx.author
 await ctx.send(member.avatar_url)
```

You can use `getpfp` to display the avatar of user by passing 1) Mention/Tag 2) Display name/ Nick Name 3) Discord ID.
`eg .getpfp @Someone`